# Why does an index update take so much time in Solr 4.10.x?

Tags: performance, indexing, solr, lucene

I am using solr 4.10.3. I have to update about 100,000 indexes. Queries are like per document

```
curl 'localhost:8900/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"org.wikipedia.ur:http/wiki/%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84","group":{"set":"wiki"}}]'
```

After starting to update this index, after 12 hours passed, only 48000 documents are updated.

Where is the problem. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using hard commit with each curl request. This forces solr to push the segment (lucene data structure for storing the indexes) to disk with every commit. Solr always write the data into new segments and looks like it force it to create 100K segments.

Solr uses mergePolicy as **TieredMergePolicy** and `mergeFactor` as **10** default parameter which merge every time solr have 10 almost equal size segments. This merge processes runs in the background using with **ConcurrentMergeScheduler** implementation.

This merge process is CPU intensive. Here you can use `softCommit` instead of `hardCommit`. That might help you.

Comment: What will be above query in case of soft commit?

Comment: Thanks, second answer gives me what I need

Comment: @Shafiq I thought I have also explained you internals of the solr. I provided you why part of the problem and suggested you as well, how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use soft commit like this one

```
curl 'localhost:8900/solr/update?softCommit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"org.wikipedia.ur:http/wiki/%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84","group":{"set":"wiki"}}]'
```